# How to render an angularjs directive inside of a slickgrid cell

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, slickgrid

We have a large number of angularJS 1.5 directives (around 100) that we use throughout our applications. We also use slickgrid almost everywhere to display mass amounts of data. A project has recently come up where it would be ideal to be able to use our directives within slickgrid cells. So I've been trying to write a slickgrid editor to generate our directives when you go to edit one of the cells.

It seems as though angularJS doesn't pick up on the directive (because slickgrid doesnt operate within angular) and doesnt attach the element to its lifecycles. so basically the base element and its settings will appear in the HTML like this:

```
<div class="slick-cell l2 r2 active selected" title="">
  <custom-directive></custom-directive>
</div>
```

but since angularJS doesn't process the directives there's no visible element in the view and none of the transcluded elements are created.

I've tried using $compile to sort of pre render the elements and then send them to slick grid, but that results in multilink errors which I'm not sure how to resolve.

I've also tried using a JS template with the hope that the template could be rendered and then used in a slickgrid editor later, but I haven't had success with that as of yet. I am still trying to make this approach work since I've seen other examples of using templates with slickgrid, but they aren't using angularJS so my situation doesn't quite fit to theirs.

To summarize I'm looking for suggestions on how I might approach this problem. I know slickgrid isn't technically supposed to be used in this fashion but there has to be a way to make this work. Reusing 100+ pieces of code to extend functionality here would be a very huge win.

Comment: Uh, how about this? https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Grid-&-DataView-Events

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-slickgrid

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane

We're already using the angular-slickgrid wrapper. but the slickgrid editors are a deeper level of the slickgrid library and therefore do not have access to the hooks provided by angular-slickgrid. I could set something like that up but it would require heavy modification to the core of slickgrid and in the end it still wouldn't solve my core issue of getting angularJS to process the directive sitting inside the  grid.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane My apologies, I explained that wrong. the editors are  a part of the angular-slickgrid, I believe. but even still, they do not have direct access to the event hooks and wouldn't really help in solving my problem anyway.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but it's possible that when DOM nodes are created, they aren't being initialised with whatever constructor it uses for the hooks. Can you call the constructor in the formatter or editior code? Alternatively, if it has a heavy footprint, there is the Async Post Render feature.

Comment: I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid and there's nothing special about the Editors, they are simple DOM elements and they use event trigger (e.g. `keyup`) just like SlickGrid does. I also used to have SlickGrid working in AngularJS as well, quite some time ago, by passing the `$scope` into the grid definition, I was able to retrieve the Controller instance and and edit item with a modal window. To put it in a simpler way, user click on an edit icon (cell), it would pass the item datacontext to an edit action that would then open a modal window (which was in Angular), not directives though